# Drupal commerce - product display view replicates products

Tags: views, commerce

I'm building a ecommerce for a fashion designer and of course every item has got variation such as color and size.
With line item it's fine, on the product display i've got the option to change color and size and with the fancy attribute module I can show a small box with the color instead of simple text.

Now I have to build a view of product display which contains title, 1 picture and price.
In order to get the price I create a relationship with the product reference but here comes the problem, it shows all the products, every variations so one item could be repeated several times in different color and different size.

I would like to show just one product of that group, then the user clicks on it and sees the product display and there he can choose the variation.

Of course I can delete the relationship, add a price field on the content type "product display" and show it in the view but I would like to know if there is another way to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known issue discussed in [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1200536). Setting the query to distinct in the queery settings under advanced within views worked for me, as described in [comment 6](http://drupal.org/node/1200536#comment-4957410).

Answer (score 2):

Not needed to add Fields in view, only create a view (Content, not Product) of Product display nodes, Format show Teaser OR other **Display entity view** already created with http://drupal.org/project/entity_view_mode - in display mode add only field you want to display

Comment: Thanks svetlio, but I need to have fields. Vote up for your answer.

Comment: Just use this in filter.
Content: Product Reference:delta (= 0)
which will show only one variation of your product.
Ca be used with fields also.